# Mostrar no Autocomplete o atributo de um usuário específico

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, autocompletar

Estou tentando fazer um autocomplete para mostrar somente o nome dos professores cadastrados. Eu acredito que o problema esteja na busca pelo atributo, já que para pegar o atributo tenho que que fazer o seguinte caminho:
`GestaoMonografiasBean` -> `Monografia` -> `Professor` -> `Usuario` -> **nome**.

Pode ser que estou fazendo uma gambiarra maluca, mas desculpa minha falta de conhecimento, sou novo nesse mundo.

Outra questão é o Converter. O problema pode estar nele também, já que estou enviando para a classe `ProfessorConverter` um objeto `Usuário`, para que ele pegue o atributo nome, para ser usado no autocomplete.

O erro que dar quando digito alguma letra para ele buscar o **nome** do professor é este abaixo, eu até entendi que ele não consegue pegar o atributo **nome** na classe `Professor`, mas na verdade ele passar pela classe `Professor` e pegaria na classe `Usuario` o nome referente ao professor. Não sei se estou fazendo certo.

> nov 19, 2017 11:04:47 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase execute
>   ADVERTÊNCIA: /paginas/GestaoMonografias.xhtml @125,58 completeMethod="#{gestaoMonografiasBean.completarProfessor}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [nome] on this ManagedType [com.daniel.monografia.model.Professor]
>   javax.el.ELException: /paginas/GestaoMonografias.xhtml @125,58 completeMethod="#{gestaoMonografiasBean.completarProfessor}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [nome] on this ManagedType [com.daniel.monografia.model.Professor]
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
>       at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete.broadcast(AutoComplete.java:480)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [nome] on this ManagedType [com.daniel.monografia.model.Professor]
>       at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManagedType.java:128)
>       at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:113)
>       at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractFromImpl.locateAttributeInternal(AbstractFromImpl.java:116)
>       at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:204)
>       at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:177)
>       at com.daniel.monografia.repository.Professores.pesquisar(Professores.java:36)
>       at com.daniel.monografia.controller.GestaoMonografiasBean.completarProfessor(GestaoMonografiasBean.java:94)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
>       at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>       at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>       ... 29 more
>
> nov 19, 2017 11:04:47 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
>   GRAVE: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [nome] on this ManagedType [com.daniel.monografia.model.Professor]
>       at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManagedType.java:128)
>       at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:113)
>       at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractFromImpl.locateAttributeInternal(AbstractFromImpl.java:116)
>       at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:204)
>       at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:177)
>       at com.daniel.monografia.repository.Professores.pesquisar(Professores.java:36)
>       at com.daniel.monografia.controller.GestaoMonografiasBean.completarProfessor(GestaoMonografiasBean.java:94)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
>       at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>       at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>       at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete.broadcast(AutoComplete.java:480)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

**Meu autocomplete**

```
<p:outputLabel value="Orientador: " for="orientador" />
                <p:autoComplete id="orientador" size="80" 
                    value="#
 {gestaoMonografiasBean.monografia.professor.usuario}" 
                    completeMethod="#
 {gestaoMonografiasBean.completarProfessor}" 
                    converter="#{gestaoMonografiasBean.professorConverter}"
                    var="usuario"
                    itemLabel="#{usuario.nome}" itemValue="#{usuario}"/>
```

**`ProfessorConverter`**, onde acho que o problema pode estar, pois estou enviando um objeto `Usuário` dentro de um objeto `Professor`, acho que estou falando merda, vocês me corrijam.

```
package com.daniel.monografia.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;

import com.daniel.monografia.model.Professor;
import com.daniel.monografia.model.Usuario;

public class ProfessorConverter implements Converter{

    private List<Professor> listaProfessores;

    public ProfessorConverter(List<Professor> listaProfessores) {
        this.listaProfessores = listaProfessores;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        System.out.println("NOME: " + value);
        if(value == null){
            return null;    
        }

        Long id = Long.valueOf(value);

        for(Professor professor: listaProfessores){
            if(id.equals(professor.getId())){
                return professor;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if(value == null){
            return null;
        }

        Professor professor = (Professor) value;

        return professor.getId().toString();
    }

}
```

O método `completarProfessor` dentro do `GestaoMonografiasBean`, por esse bean que pretendo incluir a monografia com todos os dados

```
public List<Professor> completarProfessor(String termo) {
     List<Professor> listaProfessores = professores.pesquisar(termo);

    professorConverter = new ProfessorConverter(listaProfessores);

    return listaProfessores;
}
```

E depois de chamar o método `completarProfessor` ele vai chamar o método `pesquisar` que está no meu repositório `Professores`, onde ele vai listar por **nome** quando eu inserir no campo que chama o autocomplete

```
package com.daniel.monografia.repository;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import com.daniel.monografia.model.Professor;

public class Professores implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager manager;

    public Professores(){

    }

    public Professores(EntityManager manager){
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public List<Professor> pesquisar(String nome){
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();

        CriteriaQuery<Professor> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Professor.class);
        Root<Professor> root = criteriaQuery.from(Professor.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(root);
        criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("nome"),nome + '%'));

        TypedQuery<Professor> query = manager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

**Professor.java**

```
package com.daniel.monografia.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "professor")
public class Professor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id", nullable = false)
    private Usuario usuario;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Professor other = (Professor) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Professor [id=" + id + "]";
    }

}
```

**Usuario.java**

```
package com.daniel.monografia.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name="usuario")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String nome;

    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 8)
    private Long matricula;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 8)
    private String senha;

    @Column(name = "ultimo_acessso")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date ultimoAcesso;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Character tipo;

    //Campos para usar no envio de email
    @Transient
    private String usuarioEmail = "sistemamonografia@gmail.com";
    @Transient
    private String senhaEmail = "monografia123";
    @Transient
    private String assunto;
    @Transient
    private String mensagem;

    @Transient
    private Professor professor;
    @Transient
    private List <Aluno> aluno;

    public Usuario() {
        super();

    }

    public Usuario(Long matricula, String senha) {
        super();
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.senha = senha;

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public Date getUltimoAcesso() {
        return ultimoAcesso;
    }

    public void setUltimoAcesso(Date ultimoAcesso) {
        this.ultimoAcesso = ultimoAcesso;
    }

    public Long getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(Long matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsuarioEmail() {
        return usuarioEmail;
    }

    public void setUsuarioEmail(String usuarioEmail) {
        this.usuarioEmail = usuarioEmail;
    }

    public String getSenhaEmail() {
        return senhaEmail;
    }

    public void setSenhaEmail(String senhaEmail) {
        this.senhaEmail = senhaEmail;
    }

    public String getAssunto() {
        return assunto;
    }

    public void setAssunto(String assunto) {
        this.assunto = assunto;
    }

    public String getMensagem() {
        return mensagem;
    }

    public void setMensagem(String mensagem) {
        this.mensagem = mensagem;
    }

    public Character getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(Character tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public Professor getProfessor() {
        return professor;
    }

    public void setProfessor(Professor professor) {
        this.professor = professor;
    }

    public List<Aluno> getAluno() {
        return aluno;
    }

    public void setAluno(List<Aluno> aluno) {
        this.aluno = aluno;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Usuario other = (Usuario) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Usuario [id=" + id + "]";
    }



}
```

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Consegui fazer o `autocomplete` para buscar todos os `usuários`, mas eu quero somente os `professores` . Alguém tem uma ideia ou uma dica, pois como a classe `Professor` herda os atributos de `Usuário`, logo o atributo `nome` está em `Usuário`

Meu autocomplete ficou assim depois dessa modificação

```
<p:outputLabel value="Orientador: " for="orientador" />
                <p:autoComplete id="orientador" size="80" 
                    value="#{gestaoUsuariosBean.usuario.professor.usuario}" 
                    completeMethod="#{gestaoUsuariosBean.completarUsuario}" 
                    converter="#{gestaoUsuariosBean.usuarioConverter}"
                    var="usuario"
                    itemLabel="#{usuario.nome}" itemValue="#{usuario}"/>
```

Comment: Não entendi o final, você quer só os professores e o que está exibindo não está correto ?

Comment: Blz Douglas!
Ele mostra o nome de todos os usuários, mas eu quero que mostre só o nome dos professores. 
Pelo que pesquisei acho que o problema está no método  pesquisar no banco, pois ele está pesquisando todos os nomes de usuários, acho que devo fazer algum tipo de filtro para buscar só os nomes dos professores, o problema é saber fazer isso...Acho que devo fazer um union com as classes Usuários e Professores.

Comment: Está trazendo dados de alguma outra classe que herda de Usuário ?

Comment: Sim, trás o atributo nome de todas classes que herdam de Usuário. 
Mas eu não faço o extended de Usuário em Professor, estou usando composição, não sei se essa informação é útil.

Comment: Poste sua classe Professor por favor.

Comment: Poste usuário também

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Douglas. Já editei e postei as classes

Answer (score 1):

Analisando seu código, é o seguinte:

- O seu `completeMethod` está errado pois ele aciona `gestaoUsuariosBean.completarUsuario` quando deveria acionar `completarProfessor`. Logo ele vai trazer usuários.
- Outra coisa é que você pode usufruir da orientação a objetos (Estude o assunto). Digo isso porque Professor pode e deveria herdar Usuário. Claro que não conheço seu projeto a fundo mas pelo que pude abstrair é o correto.

Mude seu `completeMethod="#{gestaoUsuariosBean.completarUsuario}"` para `completeMethod="#{GestaoMonografiasBean.completarProfessor()}"`

Comment: Vou seguir suas dicas e tentar implementar alguma coisa, posto aqui o resultado

Comment: Uma dúvida. Já que estou usando o Hibernate para mapeamento e ele usa da composição para relacionar as tabelas, não seria melhor usar a composição invés de herança? Posso estar falando besteira sei lá...